# Check if input is integer or above zero

Tags: c++

so im struggling a bit - how can i make function to check if the user input is integer?
I did try do/while... but somehow its not working.

```
void pievieno(int *a ,int jaunais,int vecais){
int jaunais_skaitlis;
cout<< "Ievadiet skaitlus" <<endl;
for (int i=vecais;i<jaunais;i++) 

{
    cin >> jaunais_skaitlis;
    a[i] = jaunais_skaitlis;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cin itself should tell you if it could read integer or not. It should have one of the error flags set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `stream >> variable`, depending of type of `variable`, the `stream` will try to process characters in order to get something, which is a valid for such variable type. If it fails to do so, `stream`s `failbit` is set, so you can check that.

```
for (int i=vecais;i<jaunais;i++) 
{
    cin >> jaunais_skaitlis;
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        // abort, user inputed something, which is not integer.
    }
    a[i] = jaunais_skaitlis;
}
```

Beware, that `stream` will do as much as it can to actually extract something from the input. Thus, if you enter `123qffe541e`, it actually is valid input, `jaunais_skaitlis` will contain `123` and rest of characters will remain in the stream (thus, failing next iteration).

If you really want to check if whole input is integer, you have to read more chars (e.g. read to `std::string`, either single word or whole line, depending on your needs) and then process that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no point in checking the data type of user's input because you've deliberately defined the input variable to be an integer using `int jaunais_skaitlis;`. Therefore, no matter what the user types in, you're getting and integer value for the input anyways.

However, what you can do it define the data type to be something other than `integer`, maybe a `float`, and then check if its an integer, float or something else.

Comment: Then how to check if the input is 'a'?

Comment: I'm not properly understanding the problem domain here. There could be many possible ways to solve this issue depending upon the program's objectives. One could simply work and compare ASCII values as well. For this, we can may be initialize the input variable using `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You should accept user's input with string, and check what's in it.
There's lots of method to check user's input. The most powerful way is regex.